# Form submission by Post method problem

Tags: php, kohana

I have a controller class which is in modules/moduleName/classes/controller/admin/ directory.
In this class I have two routines. a) action_index b) uploadZip

I have one file for UI in modules/views/uploadfile.php Code is as

```
<form method="post" action='uploadZip' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' name='file' />
<input type="text" name="xyz" value="test data" />
<input type='submit' name="upload" value='Upload' />
</form>
```

I am not getting the $_POST and $_FILES array. If I change form method from "post" to "get" then I get the form data. I am using Kohana framework. Please help me out.

Comment: well you have to use post for actually uploading files, when using GET it must simply  miss out the file information, but, you also need an input field which defines max file size 

 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />

Comment: I have just check it for test purpose. Even I had tried with simple text box for post method. It still not works.

Comment: can you provide example code of what your using to access the post information?

Comment: I am just using print_r($_POST); and it is showing an empty array

Comment: This code works exactly as posted for me on Apache.  (At least insofar as I get the value of my textbox.)  Are you using IIS?

Comment: Also, what do you get if you print_r($_FILES)?

Comment: I am using Apache web server. Also When I use print_r($_FILES); It also shows me an empty array.

Comment: Use firebug to check headers sent by browser. Also, why do you name second function `uploadZip` (not `action_uploadZip`)?

Comment: And PLEASE show your Kohana version (`3.0.11`, `3.1.3` etc)

Comment: Functions name is action_uploadZip It automatically get called when I gave uploadZip in form action

Answer (score 0):

Seems OK. Check the HTML output in your browser, maybe you have nested forms (which is not allowed)?

Comment: I have checked with view source and it shows there is only one form there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Kohana issue, not an HTML, PHP issue.  Your code works fine without Kohana.

So that being said, my guess is that you have code that is filtering out your $_POST and $_FILES variables before your check them.  Consider moving your print_r() statements to the very, very top of your "uploadZip" page.

Also, from the [Kohana User Guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/security/validation):

> The Validate object will remove all fields from the array that have not been specifically named by a label, filter, rule, or callback. This prevents access to fields that have not been validated as a security precaution.

So my guess is that you are including code that is removing these fields, since you haven't specifically listed them.

Lastly, it's good practice to use only double quotes within HTML tags -- it looks like you have a mixture of both single and double quoted tag parameters.